How to see the value of a variable in WinDbg when debugging pyx?
I compiled pyx according to the instructions here,
So that it can be debugged in WinDbg, I am now able to put a breakpoint inside the code, but the values ​​in the Locals panel do not help much.
Attached is a picture, I would like to know the value of min_bound, how can I see it?

There are some objects that are actually PyObject, such as __pyx_v_self, is there a way to see their value? Something like I do in Python: print(__pyx_v_self) ?

Minimal example:

Create three files below.
Compile with the following command: python setup.py build_ext --inplace.
Run the main.py file.
Run python.exe under WinDbg
Paste in Python import os; os.chdir("full path to the code folder")
And also the code from the main.py file and press Enter
Open helloworld.pyx in WinDbg
Put a breakpoint in the helloworld.pyx file
run the code from the main.py file again.

helloworld.pyx
from __future__ import print_function

def fib(n):
    """Print the Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a + b

    print()

def primes(int nb_primes):
    cdef int n, i, len_p
    cdef int[1000] p

    if nb_primes > 1000:
        nb_primes = 1000

    len_p = 0  # The current number of elements in p.
    n = 2
    while len_p < nb_primes:
        # Is n prime?
        for i in p[:len_p]:
            if n % i == 0:
                break

        # If no break occurred in the loop, we have a prime.
        else:
            p[len_p] = n
            len_p += 1
        n += 1

    # Let's copy the result into a Python list:
    result_as_list = [prime for prime in p[:len_p]]
    return result_as_list

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, n) -> None:
        self.fib = fib(n)
        self.primes = primes(n)
        # try see the value of self.fib and self.primes in Windbg

setup.py
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [Extension('helloworld', ["helloworld.pyx"], extra_compile_args=["-Ox", "-Zi"], extra_link_args=["-debug:full"])]
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions, gdb_debug=True, emit_linenums=True)
)

main.py
import helloworld
my_class = helloworld.MyClass(2000)
print(my_class.fib)


I suspect you're looking for something that works with Python, rather than something for Cython specifically. https://github.com/SeanCline/PyExt looks like it might be promising (see https://bjg.io/debugging-python-in-windbg/) but I haven't tried it myself so couldn't give you a definite answer.

@DavidW I checked PyExt, but it only writes that a certain object is numpy.ndarray but does not print the values.

What does print(self.min_bound, flush=True) returns?

@MarinNagy Where should I put the print command?

@ThomasWeller I added a minimal example, there is no need for a C file since everything is fine with it, when the program switches to C code you can see everything in Windbg without a problem, the whole problem is with the pyx files.
